# jQuery UI accordion not working within Safari from local directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

DISCLAIMER: This is a question from a "python coder" attempting to learn js and jQuery.

I have created an accordion as follows (filename: script.js locally):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').accordion();
});
```

I also have my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>astrobox.io | Welcome!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <h3>Data Collection</h3>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <h3>Data Analysis</h3>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <h3>Data Visualisation</h3>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm really not 100% sure what I have done wrong. Any hints at a solution would be warmly received. Do I need to change `"menu"` to a class and utilising `$('.menu')`?

These are the outside libraries I link to:

```
<title>astrobox.io | Welcome!</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Many thanks

Comment: try to load `jquery-ui.js` before `script.js` and add `jquery.js` to your script as jquery-ui depends on this

Comment: I've added all the scripts and links to outside libraries as an edit, could you let me know if these are correct and in the correct order as well. I understand the order to be important.

Comment: there could be a conflict because you add `jquery.js` twice, remove one here. (first or second line)

Comment: Removed the duplication, kept the ajax.googleapis link, still not working as correctly as it should be.

Comment: when you check your network requests (inspect element > timelines > network requests) are you successfully fetching the items that are at //? I'm curious because if you're working off the filesystem that it might not be appending the correct protocol to the request.

Comment: Hi Brody, yes. I have just edited my question to omit the items fetched that start with //

Comment: You're including jQuery, but are you also including jQuery UI? The [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) is part of jQuery UI. Seems to work fine if you do http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mrkzoa33/

Comment: Try the script locally and open in your chosen browser...

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>astrobox.io | Welcome!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#menu').accordion();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <h3>Data Collection</h3>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <h3>Data Analysis</h3>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <h3>Data Visualisation</h3>
            <div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Why does that work exactly over my version? Something to do with my script.js file?